# R XLConnect package keeps creating corrupt files

Tags: r, export-to-excel, xlsx

I am trying to use the XLConnect package with R to import some Excel data, make some modifications and then save it. Every time I do this though it corrupts the file. I tried to do the most basic thing of creating a Workbook with XLConnect and then immediately save it but even the files XLConnect is creating are corrupt. Every time I try to open them in Excel I only get an error. Here is the very simple code that I am using to try to create a file and then save it.

```
library(rJava)
library(XLConnectJars)
library(XLConnect)

wb.new <- loadWorkbook("myNewExcelFile.xlsx", create= TRUE)
saveWorkbook(wb.new)
```

Every time I do this Excel give me an error saying the file was corrupted. I can create the Workbook object in R and manipulate it but I can't save it without corruption. This is my environment:

> Windows 7 Pro 64-bit
>
> Java 1.7.0_06 64-bit
>
> RStudio ver. 0.96.331
>
> R ver. 2.15.2 64-bit

Comment: XLConnect became rather finicky for me after their latest update. This is one of several issues that I've also experienced. For me, XLConnect has seemed more stable when I write plain .xls files (and then convert them in Excel if needed).

Comment: Joran, you are right. I saved it as a '.xls' and it worked. If you put it as an answer to the question I will mark yours as the correct one.

Comment: A workbook has to have at least one sheet - XLConnect will create one without any sheets but Excel (2007 in my case) will open it as a "corrupted" workbook. If I do the sequence of loadWorbook, createSheet, saveWorkbook then I get a workbook with one empty sheet which just opens fine.

Comment: If you come across other issues please report them as mentioned in the package vignette at http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/vignettes/XLConnect.pdf

Comment: @MartinStuder That (manually creating a sheet) has sometimes worked for me, and sometimes not. I would be more proactive about filing bug reports (I use XLConnect a lot and really like it!) I just simply haven't been able to narrow anything down to something reproducible and don't want to make you chase phantom bugs.

Comment: @MartinStuder The problem I was having before this was that I was opening a `.xlsx`, modifying it and then trying to save it but it was corrupted every time. I tried to do an even simpler thing in creating a new `.xlsx` in R and then saving it but that was corrupted every time as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a complete solution, but simply a rough workaround, as I mentioned in my comment above. I have found recently that XLConnect is a bit more stable if I initially write to an older format, specifically a `.xls` file, and then convert it to `.xlsx` within Excel if needed.